# How do I get a list of a user's SharePoint group memberships across a Microsoft tenant?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api

I have a list of users and for each I want to generate a list of all SharePoint groups that user is in, across the whole tenant.

What is the best way to do this?

So far I can list every site in the tenant and then check for group membership in each site but this seems very inefficient.

Comment: Could you please add more details about the endpoints you are already using? Example: you check for a group membership - how? What do you mean by inefficient? Is it slow?

Comment: @user2250152 I am using this endpoint /_api/web/getuserbyid(' + userid + ')/?$expand=groups - my main problem is that 1000 users over 100 site collections means 100,000 calls